# How to iterate through string characters in unix shell without using external commands?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

This is not bash. This is sh.  ${foo:0:1} doesn't work. Results in bad substitution.

`foo="Hello"`

How do i print each character individually? I am looking for an approach that requires no external commands.

Comment: @MarkSetchell that's a link to the Bash manual, and the OP explicitly said, "this is not Bash".

Comment: You said, "without using external commands", but for something like this I would immediately start looking at things like `awk` or `expr` (or even `dd`): sure, they're external commands, but they have also been mainstays of shell scripting for 30 years.

Comment: @larsks Oops, yes. I'm deleting my silliness. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: There's a reason bash added the `${foo:0:1}` extension: it provides capabilities you don't have (without use of external commands) otherwise.

Comment: POSIX shell allows you to get the first character of a variable, and get everything but the first character (see `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter%%word}` in the man page. With this, you can process in a loop the characters in the variable from left to right, by removing the first character until the variable gets empty. I wander why you want to do this. Is this kind of a programming contest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment: the traditional Bourne shell doesn't really have the sort of built-in facilities for string manipulation that are available in more modern shells. It was *expected* that you would rely on external program for these features.

For example, using something as simple as `cut`, we could write:

```
foo="hello"

len=$(echo "$foo" | wc -c)
i=1

while [ "$i" -lt "${len}" ]; do
  echo "$foo" | cut -c"$i"
  i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

Which would output:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

Commands like `cut` are "standard" shell scripting commands, despite not being built into the shell itself.

Comment: Why are you targeting Bourne (using backticks and `expr`), when the OP specifies (presumably POSIX) sh?

Comment: Because I wasn't sure if `$(...)` was a posix-ism or a bash-ism, and I know this will work for Bourne and later.

Comment: Both `$( )` and `$(( ))` are defined by POSIX.2, all the way back to initial 1992 publication. (The bashism near them is `(( ))`).

Comment: I came to know pretty soon that we need to use and external command.

Answer (score 2):

As written in [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72178314/10622916) you have to rely on external commands.

Instead of running external programs once to get the string length and repeatedly for every index, I suggest to use a single `awk` call.

```
foo="hello world"

awk -v "s=$foo" 'BEGIN { l=length(s); for(i=1; i<=l; i++) print substr(s,i,1)}' /dev/null
```

which prints

```
h
e
l
l
o

w
o
r
l
d
```

Of course you could add further processing to the `awk` script or read and process the output like

```
awk ... | while IFS= read -r char
...
```

see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 1):

suggesting `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' FS="" <<<$(echo "$foo")
```

suggesting `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo="hello me"
for ((i = 0 ; i < ${#foo}; i++)); do
  echo "${foo:$i:1}"
done
```

Comment: Tip: you do not need `$` inside `::`. `"${foo:i:1}"`